# Unique ids on triangles generated from tessellation shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, shader, hlsl, tessellation

When you create a tessellation shader in HLSL, is there a way to track these new triangles with ids? I have tried using semantics such as SV_PrimitiveID in the geometry shader along with SV_InstanceID in the domain shader but they seem to output the original mesh's data. I hope to be able to store the data in a compute buffer. Any suggestions would help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could look at stream-output stage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205121(v=vs.85).aspx) to gather the generated triangles into a buffer from the geometry shader stage.

By sending the tessellation coordinates along with the vertices to the geometry shader it becomes possible to uniquely identify each triangle by three barycentric coordinate triples.